# Microsoft Store button disabled in Word 2016 for Mac

Tags: ms-office

I have a user that wants to use an add-in available on the Microsoft store. However, the store button under Add-ins on the Insert ribbon is disabled. This is in Word 2016 on OS 10.13.2. Is there a specific setting or permission that can cause this to occur?

Comment: Is this an Office 365 installation?

Comment: The MS office store provides access to components that are supposed to be independent of OS. In this case the addin was developed/tested to run on a Mac. I cannot replicate the problem. They are not using the online version of Office although it is possible they downloaded Word via  a 365 subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Found user had read only document open when attempting to use store. Opening an editable document enabled all buttons under addins.